# Python asyncio: second coroutine wrapped in a Task is not scheduled (but first is)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have written an Echo client based on `asyncio.Protocol`.
I am interested in triggering callbacks when `data_received` receives some data.

I am trying to achieve this by creating `Task`s out of coroutines in data_received, to which I then a callback via `add_done_callback`.

Here's the code of the client:

```
import asyncio

class EchoClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):

    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop
        self.tasks = None

        # To be initialised upon connection
        self.transport = None

    def send(self, msg):
        print('>', msg)
        self.transport.write(msg)

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.logon()

    def data_received(self, msg):
        print('<', msg)
        if msg == b'logon':
            task = self.loop.create_task(next(self.tasks)())
            task.add_done_callback(next(self.tasks))
        else:
            try:
                task = self.loop.create_task(next(self.tasks)())
                task.add_done_callback(next(self.tasks))
            except StopIteration:
                print('no more messages')
                return

    def eof_received(self):
        """Triggered when the other end signals it won't send any more data"""
        print('EOF received')

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        """Triggered when connection is lost"""
        print('Exception: %s', exc)
        self.loop.stop()

    def logon(self):
        self.send(b'logon')
```

The main looks like this:

```
def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    EchoClient = EchoClientProtocol(loop)

    # access recv and send here
    first_msg = b'message 1'
    second_msg = b'message 2'

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def first():
        yield EchoClient.send(first_msg)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def second(*a):
        yield EchoClient.send(second_msg)

    def tasks():
        yield first
        yield second

    EchoClient.tasks = tasks()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_connection(lambda: EchoClient, '127.0.0.1', 2000)
    loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    loop.run_forever()
    loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is the output when I run the client (it assumes an Echo server is running on port 2000 - this will do the trick if you don't have one: `socat TCP4-LISTEN:2000,fork EXEC:cat`):

```
jir@klo01 $ python3 echo_client_asyncio3.py 
> b'logon'
< b'logon'
> b'message 1'
< b'message 1'
no more messages
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "echo_client_asyncio3.py", line 76, in <module>
    main()
  File "echo_client_asyncio3.py", line 72, in main
    loop.run_forever()
  File "/home/jir/apps/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 421, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/home/jir/apps/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1389, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/home/jir/apps/lib/python3.6/selectors.py", line 445, in select
    fd_event_list = self._epoll.poll(timeout, max_ev)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

As you can see, the first coroutine is scheduled correctly: `logon` is sent and received, and `message1` is sent and received. However, `message2` doesn't seem to ever get scheduled.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`task.add_done_callback(f)` accepts a regular function and not a coroutine.

Assuming the following change:

```
def tasks():
    yield first()
    yield second()
```

This will work:

```
    task = self.loop.create_task(next(self.tasks))
    next_task = next(self.tasks)
    task.add_done_callback(
        lambda fut: self.loop.create_task(next_task))
```

Keep in mind you can use a wrapper task instead of using `add_done_callback`:

```
async def first_and_second():
    await first()
    await second()
```

Comment: That definitely fixes my code. However, a side effect is that `second` is scheduled before the message triggered by `first` arrives - which I would like to avoid and that was the reason for me to use add_done_callback in the first place:
 
    `$ python3 echo_client_asyncio3.py 
    > b'logon'
    < b'logon'
    > b'message 1'
    > b'message 2'
    < b'message 1'
    no more messages
    < b'message 2'
    no more messages
    ^C`

Comment: So, how about explicitly waiting for message 1 to arrive before scheduling message 2?

Comment: That's what I thought I was doing with my code, but clearly it's not the case.

Comment: You have added a done callback to **sending** the message.

Comment: That was a silly mistake of me. It all makes sense now.